# How to convert base64 byte array to video in ios using objective C

Tags: iphone

But in ios how to convert a byte stream to video and play in iphone, can anyone help me

```
 stream   t =    new Filestream   ("video.mp4,   FileMode.Create);
 BinaryWriter b    =    new Binary_Writer(t);
 b.write(videoData);
 t.close();
```

Comment: Base64 is a way to encode byte data as a string. The term "base64 byte array" doesn't make sense to me. Maybe you mean "a byte array I've already encoded as a base64 string"? If the byte array represents a video, how is it encoded? What format of video?

Comment: I GUESS he has byte64 data, needs to decode it and write to video.mp4

Comment: video format is .avi or .wmv and video is encoded to byte array in c#, how to decode it to video.mp4 in ios.can u please help me

Comment: video is encoded to byte array in c#, now how to decode it to video.mp4 and play it in ios,please can you help

Answer (score 1):

to decode b64, try out this library: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

use it like so:

```
NSString *videoPath = '...'; //output path for the video.mp4 
NSString *encodedString = '...'; //the encoded "data"
NSData *decodedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:encodedString];
[decodedData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: I receive a binary video file, which is base64Binary, how can I convert it back on the iPhone? What tool kits I can use? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote that to you - without anything more from your end, thats all there is